# How to define composite primary key using codeIgniter migrations?

Tags: php, codeigniter, migration

i convert my database to migrations successfully, except the following line:

```
 PRIMARY KEY (`key_id`,`user_id`);
```

Currently i doing it as:

```
$this->dbforge->add_key('key_id,user_id',TRUE);
```

but no Luck.
gives the following Error:

```
 Error Number: 1072<p>Key column 'key_id,user_id' doesn't exist</p>
```

can anyone help? 
sorry for English Grammar and if i am not clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks i found the solution my self:

```
$this->dbforge->add_key('key_id', TRUE);
$this->dbforge->add_key('user_id', TRUE);
```

here is the source [link](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/forge.html)